# This code uses the variable "ok" but it is not defined

Tags: dictionary, go, indexing

This code is functioning but I don't understand how.

In the code below hostProxy[host] may or may not contain a function. I don't understand how the variable "ok" is defined or how it gets its value. It is not defined before this line.

```
if fn, ok := hostProxy[host]; ok {
    fn.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    return
}

if target, ok := hostTarget[host]; ok {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Eh. That's such a standard construct that it's hard to know what you're asking. Do you not understand `:=`? Or the two value return map lookup? Both are covered adequately in the Go tour or pretty much any tutorial or book worth their name or the language specification if you want to read that.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations and https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+comma+ok+idiom&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered in [Spec: Index expressions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)

> An index expression on a map a of type `map[K]V` used in an [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) or initialization of the special form
>
> ```
> v, ok = a[x]
> v, ok := a[x]
> var v, ok = a[x]
> var v, ok T = a[x]
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of `ok` is `true` if the key `x` is present in the map, and `false` otherwise.

So for example this code:

```
if fn, ok := hostProxy[host]; ok {
    fn.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    return
}
```

Means to get the value associated with `host` key from the `hostProxy` map, create and store the value in the `fn` variable, and the result (whether the key was found in the map) in the `ok` variable. And this `ok` variable (which will be of type `bool`) is used as the condition of the `if` statement. So if the `host` key is in the `hostProxy` map, it goes ahead and uses it.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful. After reading your explanation, it should have been obvious but I am new around here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `ok` isn't defined before, but in your example you have `:=` which will define variables for you under the hood and will assign values obtained from `map lookup`.